# Parse JSON array

Tags: php, google-geocoder

I am using the google geocode api and it creates an array that I am not sure how to use. I need to pull specific elements from this array. Particularly the last latitude and longitude that is in the array.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "1600",
                    "short_name": "1600",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "President's Park",
                    "short_name": "President's Park",
                    "types": [
                        "establishment"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest",
                    "short_name": "Pennsylvania Ave NW",
                    "types": [
                        "route"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Washington",
                    "short_name": "Washington",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "District of Columbia",
                    "short_name": "DC",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "20500",
                    "short_name": "20500",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest, President's Park, Washington, DC 20500, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 38.8978378,
                    "lng": -77.0365123
                },
                "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 38.89918678029149,
                        "lng": -77.03516331970849
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 38.89648881970849,
                        "lng": -77.03786128029151
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}


Array
(
    [latitude] => -77.0365123
    [longitude] => 38.8978378
    [location_type] => ROOFTOP
)
```

Comment: Loop through it and pick what you need? If this `print_r` output was formatted better it would surely have helped getting some answers

Comment: Sorry, I didnt realize it needed to be formatted. That makes sense why it looked so weird. How would I output just latitude and just longitude into new variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Since you have results in JSON and the structure is clear now with more formatting, here is how you can get to lat or lng value in that result

```
$object=json_decode($json);
$lat=$object->results[0]->geometry->location->lat; // same style for lng
echo $lat;
```

**[See Fiddle Here](http://codepad.org/MBzMdRlB)**

Comment: I put back the other part and left it as a paragraph how it is output

Comment: ok do one thing please, before you output that print_r in your code, add a `<pre>` tag and then print_r that, that will result in the output being formatted correctly. Post that one in your question

Comment: That is with the pre tag. When I use the code wrap it makes it one line

Comment: I know its a JSON array but I have no idea how to get the elements out of it that it displays in the end when I use the pre tags

Comment: can you post its JSON output? like the string as it is, before decoding it? Sorry as much as I want to help this formatting isn't letting me to

Comment: Sorry i didnt know what you had meant. I uploaded the non decoded json code. What I need to get to is { "location" : { "lat" : 38.8978378, "lng" : -77.0365123 }